# How to run code any 3000m/s in android

Tags: android

I write below method and i want run this method any 3000M/S

```
public void onShakeImage() {
    Animation shake;
    shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.shake);
    arrowHelpImage.setAnimation(shake);
}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: What do you mean by 3000 m/s? Do you mean frames per second instead?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal, my mean is in ever 3 second run onShakeImage. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

mHandler = new Handler();
startRepeatingTask();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   stopRepeatingTask();
}

Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
@Override 
public void run() {
      try {
           onShakeImage(); //this function can change value of mInterval.
      } finally {
           mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, 3000);
      }
}
};

void startRepeatingTask() {
   mStatusChecker.run(); 
}

void stopRepeatingTask() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker); 
}
```

Comment: @user7386713 Then you should use Handler's postDelayed function for this purpose.i will edit!!

Comment: @user7386713 then Call startRepeatingTask()  in onCreateView instead of onCreate.rest is same.